# xml duplicate detection

Tags: java

i want to know how to  extract candidate objects from xml document?
for example, 
  "titles" from  a publication xml document.
  "titles" objects are preprocessed and stored into database to detect duplicate MD5    algorithm.
Pls,give me any suggesstions.

Comment: What is it that you’re trying to do, how are you doing it, and what isn’t working as you expected? We need a little more details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the question is how to retrieve particular data from XML. There is convenient [java XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html) API for that.